# How can I add such objects as three dots and plus

Tags: functions, front-end, core-language

What kind of objects do the red arrows point to in the following images?
[image]
[image]

Things like the "Three dots plus". What is the name of this object and how do I insert it? And also the second object in the form of a function.

How can I insert such objects into my code?

Comment: These objects are "iconized expressions". They contain some (usually large) expression, which someone decided to "compactify" and hide in this little gray packet. You can make them programmatically via [`Iconize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Iconize.html) or [interactively](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/notebook-interface/interactively-iconize-content.html?product=mathematica) by selecting the expression, Right-Click, then _Un/Iconize Selection_.

Comment: It is simply an abbreviation for large data

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment it is very valuable and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.